# php magic method __set

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to set an ambiguous variable on a class. Something along these lines:

```
<?php
  class MyClass {
    public $values;

    function __get($key){
      return $this->values[$key];
    }

    function __set($key, $value){
      $this->values[$key]=$value;
    }
  }

  $user= new  MyClass();
  $myvar = "Foo";
  $user[$myvar] = "Bar"; 
?>
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Please, tell me which language is trendy nowadays? I want to learn trendy languages and write trendy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so: http://ideone.com/gYftr

You'd use:

```
$instance->$dynamicName
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks minitech.

Answer (score 4):

As has been stated `$instance->$property` (*or `$instance->{$property}` to make it jump out*)

If you really want to access it as an array index, implement the [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface and use `offsetGet()`, `offsetSet()`, etc.

```
class MyClass implements ArrayAccess{
    private $_data = array();
    public function offsetGet($key){
        return $this->_data[$key];
    }
    public function offsetSet($key, $value){
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
    }
    // other required methods
}

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj['foo'] = 'bar';

echo $obj['foo']; // bar
```

---

**Caveat**: You cannot declare `offsetGet` to return by reference. `__get()`, however, can be which permits nested array element access of the `$_data` property, for both reading and writing.

```
class MyClass{
    private $_data = array();
    public function &__get($key){
        return $this->_data[$key];
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->foo['bar']['baz'] = 'hello world';

echo $obj->foo['bar']['baz']; // hello world

print_r($obj);

/* dumps
MyClass Object
(
    [_data:MyClass:private] => Array
        (
            [foo] => Array
                (
                    [bar] => Array
                        (
                            [baz] => hello world
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You access member variables with the -> operator.

```
$user->$myvar = "Bar";
```